# Is there amadeus API endpoint for checking if service is up and running

Tags: api, status, amadeus

I'm writing HealthIndicator actuator endpoint and would like to check if amadeus service is up and running.
Right now I'm sending GET request to https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2 but getting

> "org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found: [\n{\n    "errors": [\n        {\n            "code": 38196,\n            "title": "Resource not found",\n            "detail": "The targeted resource doesn't exist",\n            "status": 404\n        }\n    ]\n}\n            ]"

Is there endpoint on Self-Service API to check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we don't have a way to check the health of Amadeus for Developers APIs. `test.api.amadeus.com` would test the API Management Platform but not the APIs we offer. `https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2`  is a base path, not an actual endpoint so you cannot call it. We plan in the future to publish a Status Page providing health information about our APIs.